# How to stop activity when user presses Home?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a music application.  I'm having a problem: when the user presses back/home, the music continues playing.

[Here is my APK file](http://www.orkun2u.com/MyTest.apk)

How can I allow the user to return to Main Activity and clear the current activity (playing music)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onPause()` or `onStop()` and stop the music there.

Comment: Music and Video in my application is playing in WebView, So i could't use the Layout Button to stop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the `onWindowsFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your onPause() of your Activity to stop or pause the Mediaplayer.

Override the onPause() like this,

```
@Override
protected void  onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
  if(mediaplayer!=null)
{
    mediaplayer.pause();
}
}
```

And when you enter your activity once again, override the onResume() like this,

```
@Override
            protected void onResume() {
                super.onResume();

 if(mediaplayer!=null)
{
    mediaplayer.start();
}
}
```

Comment: my music and video is playing in WebView. Can you give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

toggle between the onpause and onstart is important
The onPause() method is overrided to give playerback control to this instance. 
also u can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.html)

```
package org.example.audio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AudioDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "AudioDemo";
    private static final String isPlaying = "Media is Playing"; 
    private static final String notPlaying = "Media has stopped Playing"; 

    MediaPlayer player;
    Button playerButton;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + v);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.play) {
            playPause();
        }
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.robotrock);
        player.setLooping(false); // Set looping

        // Get the button from the view
        playerButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.play);
        playerButton.setText(R.string.stop_label);
        playerButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Begin playing selected media
        demoPlay();

        // Release media instance to system
        player.release();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        player.pause();
    }

    // Initiate media player pause
    private void demoPause(){
            player.pause();
            playerButton.setText(R.string.play_label);
            Toast.makeText(this, notPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, notPlaying);
    }

    // Initiate playing the media player
    private void demoPlay(){
            player.start();
            playerButton.setText(R.string.stop_label);
            Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, isPlaying);
    }

    // Toggle between the play and pause
    private void playPause() {
        if(player.isPlaying()) {
          demoPause();
        } else {
          demoPlay();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: All my Music and Video is playing in WebView. So, I couldn

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks back button the control goes inside the following method (Insert this method in your code)

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    // code to pause or stop the music!!!!
            }
            **return false;**
        }
```

Comment: Dear Patil, Can you give me clear on this? because i am very new to android.

Comment: I am not able to download your apk
My thinking and elaboration is;

1. Yo have two activities in your project -- Main and Current

2. In your current activity put the above method

3. when user clicks on BACK button, control goes into this method

4. so write code inside this method to stop or pause your music and then simply write finish();

5. finish(); will call your Main Activity

Got the Idea?